# Page not found (404) adding a Django page

Tags: django

So I am trying to link up a page on my blog. I have created the template, view and URL for the page but it keeps throwing a 404 error. Could someone please look over my code and help me figure out the issue?

**add_post.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<header>
    <div class="post-caption mt-4">
        <div class="text-center-caption">
            <h1 class="display-5 fw-bolder text-shadow">Add Your Post</h1>
            <p class="lead text-shadow fw-bold">Tell us about your favourite game</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

{%endblock%}
```

**views.py:**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
    from django.views.generic import View, CreateView, ListView
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from .models import Post
    from .forms import CommentForm

class AddPost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py:**

```
from .views import AddPost, PostList, PostDetail, PostLike
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>/', PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
    path('add_post/', AddPost.as_view(), name='create_post'),
]
```

Comment: `template_name = 'about.html'` = `template_name = 'add_post.html'` ?

Comment: share your url you entering  in browser.

Comment: @khadimhusen https://8000-jrdnbrkfld-pp4gamerneti-yxcaq01qnc1.ws-eu47.gitpod.io/add_post/ is the url.

Comment: @JSRB didn't see that, thankyou. still doesn't work as intended though.

Comment: try this http://localhost:8000/home/add_post/

try this http://localhost:8000/summernote/add_post/

Comment: @khadimhusen both of these do not work. I am running server through gitpod and the URL provided is the one created when I runserver

Comment: show your projects urls.py file

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('', include('blog.urls'), name='blog_urls'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]

Comment: @khadimhusen FIXED! I changed the url to path('summernote/add_post/', AddPost.as_view(), name='create_post'), 

it now works. how would I go about being able to remove the summernote/ from the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the URL pattern is sensitive. You have a "catchall" URL defined with `path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),`.
Therefor `add_post` could be a valid slug for a post, which is causing the conflict.

Just change the order of your URL patterns to the following:

```py
from .views import AddPost, PostList, PostDetail, PostLike
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>/', PostLike.as_view(), name='post_like'),
    path('add_post/', AddPost.as_view(), name='create_post'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```